# how to get record id using button click in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a VF page which contains record id, name of account object and a button for each and every record as shown in image.

[image]
 If i click the button for particular record, the respected record id should be displayed in same visualforce page. For that i created a class and VF page as given below.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="one" action="{!save}">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock id="one">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accs}" var="a">
                <apex:column value="{!a.id}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:commandButton value="click" action="{!save}" reRender="one"/>
                    <apex:param assignTo="{!accid}" value="{!a.id}"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>  
        ID:{!accid}
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class one{
    public string acName{set;get;}
    public integer acPhone{set;get;}
    public List<Account> accs{set;get;}
    public ID accid {set;get;}

    public pagereference save(){
        accs = [select id,name,phone,type from account limit 5];

        return null;
    }
}
```

I am unable to get this requirement. Could anyone please help me in this????

### Updated COde

```
<apex:page controller="one" action="{!save}"> 
    <apex:form > 
        <apex:pageBlock id="one"> 
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accs}" var="a"> 
                <apex:column value="{!a.id}"/> 
                <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/> 
                <apex:column > 
                    <apex:commandButton value="click" action="{!save}" reRender="one"/> 
                        <apex:param value="{!a.id}" assignTo="{!accid}"/> 
                </apex:column> 
            </apex:pageBlockTable> 
            <apex:pageBlockSection > 
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > 
                ID:{!accid} 
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
            </apex:pageBlockSection> 
            </apex:pageBlock> 
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Class

```
public class one{ 

    public string acName{set;get;} 
    public integer acPhone{set;get;} 
    public List<Account> accs{set;get;} 
    public string accid {set;get;} 

    public pagereference save(){ 
        //accid = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'); 
        accs = [select id,name,phone,type from account limit 5]; 
        return null; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO as per your updated code.

Issue in your command button. Your `apex:param` should be inside command button and give param name as well. This should work for you.

```
<apex:commandButton value="click" action="{!save}" reRender="one"> 
      <apex:param name="accountId" value="{!a.id}" assignTo="{!accid}"/> 
</apex:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're re-rendering the page block. your string Id is outside the page block. Try doing this change.

```
<apex:page controller="one" action="{!save}">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock id="one">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accs}" var="a">
            <apex:column value="{!a.id}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:commandButton value="click" action="{!save}" reRender="one"/>
                <apex:param assignTo="{!accid}" value="{!a.id}"/>
            </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
   <apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
              ID:{!accid}
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:pageBlockSection>         
  </apex:pageBlock>      
</apex:form>
```

Comment: Hi Amr Ibrahim, 
I may think so, this would not be work. because page block is just to display something in a block of  section.

Comment: @KSKumaar I've updated the code ... my idea is the issue is with re-rendering

Comment: I followed your instructions. No results came even changed the code.

Comment: Thanks Amr Ibrahim,
With help of you and @Ratan. I got solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

**apex:Param** doesn't work with **apex:commandButton** as it work with **apex:commandLink**

Need to rerender a dummy element in your page, which helps to passes the correct value to controller method.

See [blog](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/04/passing-parameters-with-a-commandbutton/) on the same from Jeff Douglas. This will help.

May be you can try below code:

**VF Page**:

```
<apex:page controller="one" action="{!save}">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock id="one">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accs}" var="a">
                <apex:column value="{!a.id}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:commandButton value="click" action="{!click}" rerender="dummy" >
                        <apex:param value="{!a.id}" assignTo="{!accId}" name="paramId"/>
                     </apex:commandButton>   
                </apex:column>

            </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlock>  
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class**:

```
public class one{

    public List<Account> accs {get;set;}
    // the variable being set from the commandbutton
    public String accId  {get;set;}


    public pagereference save(){
        accs = [select id,name,phone,type from account limit 5];

        return null;
    }

    public Pagereference click(){
        System.debug('###'+accid);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass Your parameter value inside command button. Try below code snippet.

```
<apex:page controller="one" action="{!save}">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock id="one">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accs}" var="a">
                <apex:column value="{!a.id}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:commandButton value="click" action="{!save}" reRender="two">
                    <apex:param assignTo="{!accid}" value="{!a.id}"/>
                    </apex:commandButton>
                </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
      </apex:pageBlock>
      <apex:outputPanel id="two">
            ID:{!accid}
        </apex:outputPanel> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```